# How do I find the ip address of a Google search page using Python

Tags: python-3.x, subdomain

New to Python programming and trying to solve a coding project.
I am trying to write a piece of code that will access a subpage within a website.  I'm able to access the main page of the site using it's ip to .connect, and then using .sendall and .recv to get the main page's basic info.
Now I wan't to move on and capture a search page.

In this specific example: If you type keywords into the address bar (using Chrome at this moment), you get a page of search results.  I'm trying to capture the raw data of that page and dump it into a file.  I can access the main page ip address for Google using .gethostbyname, but the url for the search page is a string of words.  I haven't a clue how to write code that will allow access that page, or to send the search words to trigger the same response from Google, allowing me to capture that data as an answer to .sendall.

Is there a way for me to access this page, which was obviously created and sent back to my web browser, using Python?  If I can't by using a simple .connect and .recv code, is there another/bette way?

All recommendations appreciated.  Never posted code, so excuse any etiquette errors:

```
import socket
import sys

try:
  mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except socket.error:
  print("Failed to create socket.")
  sys.exit()
try:
  host = (socket.gethostbyname("www.google.com"), 80)
except socket.gaierror:
  print("Failed to get host")
  sys.exit()
```

## print (host)

## print(type(host))

```
mysock.connect(host)
message = b"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n"
try:
  mysock.sendall(message)
except socket.error:
  print("Failed to send")
  sys.exit()
data = mysock.recv(5000)
mysock.close()
```

Comment: OK so, just to confirm, you wrote your own socket connection in Python and connected to Google? Good, you'll learn something that way, but just to let you know if in the future you don't want to go through the work, there is a built in`urllib` library that does all that for you, it's just one line to connect and get a response. Would not recommend using this on the first time so that you understand how it works.

Comment: Secondly, and more importantly, the reason someone downvoted you is that you didn't post any code up here showing proof that you attempted to connect. Good explanation, but please post your code.

Comment: @ytpillai: `requests` isn't built-in, but it is a lot more convenient than trying to do all this by hand. Even using `urllib` (which is in the standard library) would be a lot more convenient than trying to do this by hand.

Comment: @user2357112 yup, but the goal of OP is to learn and not necessarily just get something done, so making his own sockets will help to that extent rather than the convenient approach. Although thanks for catching that slip-up about `requests`.

Comment: "the url for the search page is a string of words" - the URL for the search page is not a string of words. If you type `new apple iphone` into your address bar, Chrome will not actually attempt to treat `new apple iphone` as a URL. It'll build a url like `https://www.google.com/search?q=new+apple+iphone&othercrap=thatyoucanignore` and use that.

Comment: I just posted my code for review.  It's simple, but mostly for learning.

Comment: Thanks for the urllib reference ytpillai.  I am walking before running, and am working with the more basic ways of structuring more complex codes (as you stated).  I'm self learning and this makes it easier, though slower.

Comment: thanks for the comment, user2357112.  I know it's not just a string of words.  I was just rushing to post, and perhaps used the wrong description.  I do like the breakdown of how the search url is built, thanks.

Comment: I don't see why the downvote on this question. It's more in accordance with SO rules with many others I've seen, including the ones I've posted lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you initially create a connection socket, your operating system reserves a "file" space (in quotes on purpose, not going to go into it now), that you create on your machine. The operating system then designates a port on your system for the file space that you made, and gives you back a file descriptor, describing its location. This port is where you send and receive data.

When you run the `connect` method to connect to some Google URL, the `socket` library automatically decides that you should use a specific protocol to make the connection, and does some initial communication with the server to create a flow. This flow is where you will send one request, split up into packets of the same size, and receive a response from the server in the same way.

To create the request, which is basically just a string sent initially to Google's servers that tells them what you want and, more importantly, how you want it, we need to do make something extra called an SSL request. If you'll notice, the correct URL to Google is `https://google.com` and not `http://google.com` (although the latter redirects), because you want to negotiate a specific private key to encrypt your communication and hide it from others who might see it. Once you have done your `connect` magic, you send this SSL request with the `send` method, normally the request is automatically created by the Python library. you then receive your response, which is the response headers (values mapped to one another giving you some initial info on what you are getting), and then your body, which is HTML code.

Let's delve into the request a bit more. When you submit a search to Google, the search is saved in the URL that you requested. as @user2357112 said, a search for `new apple iphone` becomes `https://www.google.com/search?q=new+apple+iphone&...`. Everything before the equals sign is a `GET parameter` and everything after it is its value. For your purposes, you only care about the `q=` portion, which represents the search keywords you entered into the search bar. Everything else should remain the same, separated by ampersands (&).

Once you have sent a request to that URL and gotten your HTML response, you have to parse it to get the search results. Please make a separate question for that if you have to, since each post should only have one question to answer.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, very informative.  As to how this relates to altering the code I've written, I'm understanding it incorrectly.  I understand this as I will substitute the, message = b"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n", code with, message = b"https://www.google.com/search?q=my+ip+address&oq=my+ip+address".  I tried this and the code sits, waiting for a response that doesn't come.  Would you explain what I'm missing, getting wrong?  Thanks

Comment: So, you're close. But keep in mind that just because the only thing you see when making the request in the browser is the URL, does not mean that that is the whole request that was sent. Your `GET / HTTP/1.1 \r\n\r\n` is a starting point. The slash after `GET` represents the path you are trying to access, in your case everything after the slash (with the slash included) after `google.com`. After `HTTP/1.1` put a space, and then the domain you are trying to access. However, `google.com` actually redirects to `www.google.com` and you aren't implementing that, so just put `www.google.com`.

Comment: After that because you are using HTTPS, you have to negotiate an SSL connection. For that I'd suggest you read up on how to make an SSL socket in Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html)